# Why is part of my GIF.js animation covered in black?

Tags: javascript, gif, animated-gif

I'm creating a GIF based on a Canvas animation using [GIF.js](https://jnordberg.github.io/gif.js/tests/canvas.html). However, only a portion of my GIF is visible, with the rest covered in black. How do I make the full animation appear?

[image: glitched GIF animation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to set the height and width of your Canvas element before animating.

```js
let canvas:HTMLCanvasElement=document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 390;
```

[image: fixed GIF animation]